# Calling form submit to a dynamically created form on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dynamic, jquery-on

In my JQuery file I am dynamically creating a form inside of an empty DIV tag. When the user clicks on the form's button I call e.PreventDefault() to allow me to pass an AJAX call to a php script. On the success of the AJAX call I'd like to continue with the form submit. Everything is working up to the point where I would like to continue with submitting the form.

Since the form is dynamic, to target the form I use the following:

```
 $('#empty_div').on('click', '#submit_button', function (e) {...
```

Everything works, AJAX call works and does what it's supposed to, but can't figure out how to submit the original form which will redirect me to Paypal.
So after the AJAX call how can I call something like the .submit() function?

$('#form-name').submit() doesn't work and I can't seem to get .trigger() to work either.

Sorry if this is a bit long winded, I'm just trying to provide all the information I can to help with solutions.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all the help. Finally figured out, that there's no need to try and resubmit the form when I can just run the AJAX and form submit synchronously using the `async: false` option in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the form submit using

```
$('#form-name')[0].submit()
```